# Unable to find files because Amazon EKS Statefulset replicas switching between pods and volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-statefulset

I've created a Kubernetes `StatefulSet` in Amazon EKS with 3 replicas.  This Statefulset is used for the purposes of deploying a web application that allows users to upload and download files (persistent data), hence the preference for a `StatefulSet`.

During the `StatefulSet` initialization, my container creates directories to save the persistent data in on the mount point, `demo-data`: `/demo-data/files` and `/demo-data/tempFiles`.

Below is the headless `Service` and `StatefulSet` yaml.  Note that the `PVC` is using a `PV` of type `gp2` on AWS.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-web-server-service
  namespace: demo-namespace
  labels:
    app: demo
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: demo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: demo-web-server
  labels:
    app: demo
  namespace: demo-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  serviceName: demo-web-server-service
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1001
        runAsGroup: 1001
        fsGroup: 1001
      containers:
      - image: 870023218324.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo:stable
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: demo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: WEBSERVER_ROOT_PATH
            value: "/"
          - name: DEMO_MONGO_HOSTNAME
            value: demo-mongo-service # Must match name of headless mongo service
          - name: DEMO_MONGO_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: demo-creds
                key: username
          - name: DEMO_MONGO_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: demo-creds
                key: password
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /demo-data
            name: demo-app-data
      initContainers:
      - image: 870023218324.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo:stable
        name: init-demo
        # This container starts up, creates subdirectories we need in the filesystem,
        # and is terminated before the actual container is run.
        command:
        - "/bin/mkdir"
        args:
        - "-p"
        - "/demo-data/files"
        - "/demo-data/tempFiles"
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /demo-data
            name: demo-app-data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: demo-app-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

I've run into issues when attempting to save files on the `PVC`'s created by the `StatefulSet`, which to my understanding, should be separate from one another.  For example, the following files may be uploaded using the web application GUI:

- file-1.txt
- file-2.txt
- file-3.txt

And upon inspecting each of the replicas, it turns out `file-1.txt` and `file-2.txt` are saved in `demo-pvc-0` while `file-3.txt` is in `demo-pvc-1` for example.  This leads to read and write errors, since the user may attempt to download `file-3.txt` while the web application is currently using `demo-pvc-0`.  There is no consistency; EKS seems to be randomly switching between the replicas and their respective `PVC`s and nothing is in sync.  The user is unable to tell since the web application is identical between replicas.

Are there any errors in my configuration or additional things to look out for which might be causing the files uploaded to the web server to be randomly saving to different `PVC`s on the `StatefulSet`?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? All requests to go to the same pod?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, exactly.  Unless this pod happens to go down for whatever reason.  If all requests are not going to the same pod, it would be good to maintain symmetry and sync between all pod filesystems so randomly switching does not matter.

Comment: I think what you are really needing in your design is a database that can be used by multiple pods for data access. Your current design just doesn't really work with multiple instances unless you used something like NFS for the volumes, but that would introduce its own set of problems.

Comment: @jordanm Good point.  As it is now, we are using MongoDB only for user authentication.  Need to look in to taking advantage of it for file saving/retrieval.  I wasn't sure if the behavior I was experiencing is expected behavior of EKS/Kubernetes StatefulSets though.

Answer (score 0):

About the headless service, from the K8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services):

> For headless Services, a cluster IP is not allocated, kube-proxy does
> not handle these Services, and there is no load balancing or proxying
> done by the platform for them. How DNS is automatically configured
> depends on whether the Service has selectors defined.

On the other side, Statefulset does not allow to share pv/pvc and thus the files.

Some possible solutions can be:

- replace Statefulset with Deployment so all the pods share the same pv/pvc and can modify the files regardless of the pod that receive the request.
- use session affinity. You can add a service of type clusterIp and then enable session affinity from the configuration file with
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
- modify the architecture of your solution with a shared component, such as a database or a NFS filesystem, that keeps the integrity of the system and allow you to access the files.